# Randomly sample numpy columns using Cython

Tags: python, numpy, random, cython, cpython

I would like to sample columns from a large Numpy matrix a million times. I am achieving satisfactory speed using Python; however, I aim to repeat this process tens of thousands of time. At this scale, speed becomes an issue, and I am looking for ways to improve performance. I am leaning towards Cython, but I am a novice in this sector. I read the Numpy documentation and combed through online tutorials, but the suggestions do not seem straightforward.

I am wondering if there is a way, in Cython, to randomly sample N columns from a numpy matrix. The Python implementation of the logic I aim to optimize is written below:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
random.seed(888)

num_cols = 6000
range_num_cols = range(num_cols)
random_matrix = np.random.random((20, num_cols))
for _ in range(1_000_000):
    random_matrix[:, random.sample(range_num_cols, 5)]
```

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but please take a look at the new random interface in Numpy. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html It's faster than than the old generator, and it generally only needs minor changes to your code to use the new interface. Also, the new PCG64 generator uses less RAM & has better statistical properties than the old Mersenne Twister generator.

Comment: @PM2Ring Indeed it is more performant! Thank you - will look into this page further.

Comment: You can transpose your array so to make accesses faster (not the transpose function do not physically transpose your array so a copy is required).